# How to search two strings followed by 4 digits in Hive SQL

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, rlike

I am trying to search for this pattern ab1234. I tried `col like 'ab[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'` `col like '(ab)[0-9]{4}'` `col like 'ab####'`  None of these are working. I checked this website https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp, but it is not very helpful. Any advice is appreciated :)

Comment: Are there any preceding or trailing characters in addition to AB1234?  Do you want to look for lowercase ab or uppercase AB?

Comment: @donPablo sorry, that was a typo. I am only looking for lower case. thank you

Comment: use `rlike` instead of `like` for matching regular expressions. `col rlike 'ab[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`

Comment: @mck thank you, but the results were giving all the row contain this pattern

Comment: Isn't that what you're trying to do???

Answer (score 1):

Use rlike for regexp check:

```
col rlike 'ab\\d{4}' --containing ab and 4 digits in any place of the string
```

Or more strict pattern:

```
col rlike '^ab\\d{4}$' --Exactly ab and 4 digits, no other characters before or after
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where col rlike 'ab[0-9]{4}'
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).